# Vue error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Proxy.render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I found a few questions like mine, but none were clear enough to solve my specific problem.

I have this code in my Test.Vue component that is imported into my App.vue file.

P.S. Everything was working perfectly fine yesterday when I was working on this, I wasn't getting any error at all doing this. I just closed my laptop and today opened it up again to work on it and started getting this error when I refreshed my page.

```
<template>
    <div class = "test">
        <input type="text" v-model="title"> <br/>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p>{{user.lastName}}</p>
        <p v-if="showName">{{user.firstName}}</p>
        <p v-else>Nada</p>

        <!-- <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items>{{item.title}}</li>
        </ul> -->

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'test',
    data() {
        return{
            title: 'Hello World',
            user: {
                firstName:'John',
                lastName:'Doe'
            },
            showName: true,

            // items: [
            //  {title: 'Item One'},
            //  {title: 'Item Two'},
            //  {title: 'Item Three'}
            // ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped> 
</style>
```

With what I have in my code -- having commented the lines that create  in my `<template>` and the items:[] in , everything

> vue.esm.js?efeb:1741 TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of
>   undefined
>       at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-dc87507c","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Test.vue
>   (0.b8f1eab6988182beecb6.hot-update.js:7), :37:59)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.esm.js?efeb:4544)
>       at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2788)
>       at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:3142)
>       at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?efeb:3219)
>       at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.esm.js?efeb:2981)
>       at Array.eval (vue.esm.js?efeb:1837)
>       at flushCallbacks (vue.esm.js?efeb:1758)

Comment: Try to compile again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Close the present working tab on the browser.Restart your development server, and you get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just works fine ,make sure when you uncomment your commented code you put quotes(") after `items`

```
<li v-for="item in items">{{item.title}}</li>
```

That's all it should works.

Here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6ab8vtp/)

If you are still getting it, just close the serve and start again.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Quick question about the server. I am obviously a newbie so I need some clarification. When I do 'npm run dev' in my terminal, it runs correctly and gives me my localhost:8080 server, and it tells me that it is currently running. How do I get out of that and at what point should I do 'npm build dev'? Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, but I still keep getting the same error in my console. A comment above said try to compile again, how might i do that?

Comment: did you try restarting the 'npm run serve'?

Comment: I tried doing "npm run dev" and it didn't fix it. Am i supposed to do more than that?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm using Nuxt. The component seems to decide to ignore the state that it should be able to access randomly.

Comment: Fixed my problem.

It turns out, the state that I was trying to access didn't exist in the way I thought it did. So my component was wired up correctly, but I had a Vuex Store action that was committing a mutation with 'undefined' instead of the data that I was expecting it to have.

So when the component tried to render, one of my state properties was actually undefined and I was trying to access a property of that undefined property.

I think either more rigorous tests or using some strong types with TypeScript would have helped me catch this issue a bit earlier, not sure.

Comment: Oh great! Post it as an answer. It will help others

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an end quote here:

```
<li v-for="item in items>{{item.title}}</li>
```

You should add a quote after `items`. It will work then.

Comment: i fixed that in my code but i'm still having the same error. I think its a server issue and not the code itself, the code itself is correct. What part of Vue am I supposed to redo stopping then continuing my work?

Answer (score 1):

TypeError has told you about all things so clearly. first, you should know who is the Proxy.render, when it load ,what is happening, OK ?
and then ,the property 'title' of undefined at this render, it means when this page rendering ,the instance, maybe it be called 'vm.$el', can't find this property, but it need this property, so you need initialize this property correctly.
example:
if you write this in template:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item">{{item[a.b].title}}</li>
```

and you defined data like this:

```
a:{},


items: [{title: 'Item One'}],
```

you will get :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXW52.png)

because when it rendering ,can't find a.b